# Creating a gimmick monitor profile?

Tags: macos, display, color-profiles

I want to create a monitor profile which is not an accurate calibration, but actually remaps colors such that the monitor emits only red light — the blue and green channels are always 0. Preferably, it should emit the grayscale version of the input image ((weighted) average of all three channels) on the red channel.

Is this possible, and if so, what software should I use to create such a profile?

My target platform is Mac OS X. The color profiles it uses are `.icc` files; I don't know anything about their format.

I have tried abusing the built-in profile creation assistant, but it does not have enough range in its color adjustments to produce this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with color profiles, but maybe this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A tool you could use for your color profile is the Apple Display Calibration Utility.
A tutorial on using it is found [here](http://www.computer-darkroom.com/colorsync-display/colorsync_1.htm).
(Was that the tool that didn't have enough flexibility for your needs? and why?)

Some links to resources on ICC profiles are :

[International Color Consortium](http://www.color.org/iccprofiles.html)
For the technically-minded, download a free book on the mechanics of writing profiles.

[International Color Consortium](http://www.color.org/index.html)
The folks that put the ICC into color management have technical information, articles, and other resources about color and ICC profiles.

[Adobe - ICC profile downloads for Mac OS](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4074)
Download an archive of RGB & CMYK ICC profiles for OS X.

[Chromix](http://www.chromix.com/)
Have custom ICC profiles created for your system and exchange profiles with others.

[Legion Paper](http://www.legionpaper.com/digital/icc.htm)
Download generic profiles or obtain their custom profiles through listed resellers.